# Case_when error 'x must be a character vector, not a double vector'?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to use case_when() to categorize observations based upon a four digit number (which is saved as a character/string variable).

My data is as follows:

```
Form
2 1 0 1
1 0 1 2
2 2 0 0 
2 1 0 1
```

I am using case_when() as follows:

```
dat <- dat %>%
mutate(FormName = case_when(
(form == '2 1 0 1') ~ 'Open Left', 
(form == '1 0 1 2') ~ 'Open Right', 
(form == '2 2 0 0') ~ 'Spread', 
TRUE ~ 0))
```

Which should produce:

```
Form        FormName
2 1 0 1     'Open Left'
1 0 1 2     'Open Right'
2 2 0 0     'Spread'
2 1 0 1     'Open Left'
```

Instead, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `FormName`.
x must be a character vector, not a double vector.
ℹ Input `formation` is `case_when(...)`.
```

I do not understand why this is occurring, as the column 'form' is a character variable? Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: could you paste the output of `dput(head(dat$form))`  here

Comment: c("2 1 0 1", "1 0 1 2", "3 1 0 0", "1 2 0 1", "1 2 0 1", "3 1 0 0"

Comment: Slightly different from the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this:

create a named vector and use the vector

```
vct = c('2 1 0 1' = "Open Left", '1 0 1 2' = "Open Right", '2 2 0 0' = "Spread")
dat %>%
  mutate(FormName  = vct[form])
```

Comment: Does this apply over hundreds of observations?

Comment: @rogues77 yes. Try it out

Comment: I'm a little unclear--when creating the vector how does it know what column to reference? Ie: it doesn't specify to which column '2 1 0 1' is in.

Comment: @rogues77 The vct is named. So the form will pick out the value corresponding to the given name. eg if `form=c("2 1 0 1", "1 0 1 2", "3 1 0 0", "1 2 0 1", "1 2 0 1", "3 1 0 0" ,"1 0 1 2")` then try doing `vct[form]` and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the last condition of the case_when statement, `TRUE ~ 0`. The 0 is a numeric, but the other conditions of the case_when return a character, and R requires all values in a column to be the same data type.
You should change that last condition to `TRUE ~ '0'`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).